can not find .env from s3 in elastic beanstalk app
I would like to have my .env file into my streamlit elastic beanstalk app.
For that I downlaoded the .env file from my s3 using .ebextensions folder:
Parameters:
  bucket: 
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: "Name of the Amazon S3 bucket that contains your file"
    Default: "bucket"
  fileuri: 
    Type: String
    Description: "Path to the file in S3"
    Default: "https://bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/.env"
  authrole:
    Type: String
    Description: "Role with permissions to download the file from Amazon S3"
    Default: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  /tmp/.env:
    mode: "000777"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    source: { "Ref" : "fileuri" }
    authentication: S3AccessCred

##############################################
#### Do not modify values below this line ####
##############################################

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3AccessCred:
          type: "S3"
          roleName: { "Ref" : "authrole" } 
          buckets: { "Ref" : "bucket" }

container_commands:
  1_file_transfer_1:
    command: "mkdir -p storage"
  2_file_transfer_2:
    command: "mv /tmp/.env storage"

I can see the .env in the var/app/current/storage but when I checked for the list of directories inside my streamlit app there is no storage directory (and no .env)
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["app/Home.py","--browser.serverAddress","0.0.0.0","--server.enableCORS","false","--server.port","80"]

if anybody can help that would be great.
Thanks
I have a no .ebignore or .gitignore in the .zip app
